# Extract int from string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe `df` as

```
A B
1 V2
3 W42
1 S03
2 T02
3 U71
```

I want to have a new column (either at it the end of `df` or replace column `B` with it, as it doesn't matter) that only extracts the int from the column `B`. That is I want column `C` to look like

```
C
2
42
3
2
71
```

So if there is a 0 in front of the number, such as for 03, then I want to return 3 not 03

How can I do this?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can convert to string and extract the integer using regular expressions.

```
df['B'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Comment: Nice one!  For future readers: This can also be done with a **compiled** regex for more complicated expressions.  Simple example: `exp = re.compile('\d+')`.  Then use `exp` in the `str.extract(exp)` call.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is always exactly one leading letter

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str[1:].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

First set up the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'B' : ['V2', 'W42', 'S03', 'T02', 'U71']})

df.head()
```

Then do the extraction and cast it back to ints

```
df['C'] = df['B'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little loop to do this , as I didn't have my strings in a DataFrame, but in a list. This way, you can also add a little if statement to account for floats :

```
output= ''
input = 'whatever.007'  

for letter in input :
        try :
            int(letter)
            output += letter

        except ValueError :
                pass

        if letter == '.' :
            output += letter
```

output = float(output)

or you can int(output) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Preparing the DF to have the same one as yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'B' : ['V2', 'W42', 'S03', 'T02', 'U71']})

df.head()
```

Now Manipulate it to get your desired outcome:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\d+', x).group())

df.head()


    A   B   C
0   1   V2  2
1   3   W42 42
2   1   S03 03
3   2   T02 02
4   3   U71 71
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it if you don't want to use regualr expressions:
I used `map()` function to apply what is needed on each element of the column.
So like this:

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
df['C'] = list(map(lambda x: int(x.lower().strip(letters))   ,  df['B']))
```

Output will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Used `apply` and it works just fine too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'B' : ['V2', 'W42', 'S03', 'T02', 'U71']})
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:]))
df['C']
```

Output:

```
0     2
1    42
2     3
3     2
4    71
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, just as [@Lokesh A. R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815357/lokesh-a-r) has answered above, but this won't work in all cases.
When you get the error `pattern contains no capture groups` this is what you should do. According to the
[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) you to add parentheses to specify *capture group*.

```
df["B"].str.extract('(\d+)')
```