# split column to extract numerical value from each row in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe. - df

```
    year    month   number
0   2001    01  month_reported 0 year_reported 0 dtype:int64
1   2001    02  month_reported 1 year_reported 1 dtype:int64
2   2001    03  month_reported 2 year_reported 2 dtype:int64
3   2001    04  month_reported 5 year_reported 5 dtype:int64
4   2001    05  month_reported 1 year_reported 1 dtype:int64
```

and

```
df.dtypes

year      object
month     object
number    object
dtype: object
```

I need a dataframe as,

```
        year    month   number
    0   2001    01        0
    1   2001    02        1
    2   2001    03        2
    3   2001    04        5
    4   2001    05        1
```

can someone please post the code? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract int from string in Pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376387/extract-int-from-string-in-pandas)

Comment: Additionally you'd want to provide `expand=False` to return a series object.

Comment: Hey Nickil, thanks for the comment and link.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.number = df.number.apply( lambda x: int(x.split()[1]))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.